# Update Parent Id In Existing Child Record

Tags: relationships, child-to-parent

I am a new APEX learner.
I created two custom objects : Book & Author, where Author being Parent and Book being child object.
I created **Child** : book record **'Harry Potter'** with **Parent** : **'J K Rowling'**.[image: Book Record With Author]

Now I Wanted to Change the author to myself so I performed the following operation:

```
Author__c aut=[SELECT Id FROM Author__c WHERE Name LIKE 'Ravi%'];
system.debug('Author '+aut.Id);
Book__c bc=[SELECT Id, Name, Author__r.Id, Author__r.Name FROM Book__c WHERE Name LIKE 'harry     potter%'];
system.debug(bc.Name+', Author: '+bc.Author__r.Name+', author Id: '+bc.Author__r.Id);
bc.Author__r.Id=aut.Id;
system.debug(bc.Author__r.Id);
update bc;
bc=[SELECT Id, Name, Author__r.Id, Author__r.Name FROM Book__c WHERE Name LIKE 'harry potter%'];
system.debug(bc.Name+', Author: '+bc.Author__r.Name+', author Id: '+bc.Author__r.Id);
```

This Executed successfully, but author wasn't changed :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
bc.Author__c =aut.Id;
```

Comment: This is telling it to change the actual Id which is not possible. bc.Author__r.Id=aut.Id;

Comment: Not Working. A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: Author__c